# jQuery-validate - Required validation on tab out

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate.js for my front end validations. The email and other validations work on  tab out, but the required validations work only on submitting the form. Is it possible to have all my required validations to work on tab-out as well. Here is a link from the site for the reference code and behaviour: http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/

UPDATE:
Adding the below piece of code inside the .validate function worked.

```
    onfocusout: function(element) {
       this.element(element);
    },
```

Here is the link - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vLKUE/)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below rather than inside your OP.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise. Done. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the below piece of code inside the .validate function worked.

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
   this.element(element);
},
```

Here is the link - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vLKUE/)

Answer (score 1):

you should create a `blur` function for your validate controls. 
for example:

```
 $("#password").on("blur", function () {
      if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
           alert("Please enter your password");//or any process you want to be done
      }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. But then, that is without using the plugin. I want to use the jquery validator.

Comment: i think it's better to use this event for your required fields, instead of jquery validator. because i think jquery validator does not have a function for required validators to work at focus-out.

Comment: The problem with blur is that if you use in two or more fields, you might have problems.

Answer (score 0):

create blur event handler that validates an element use jquery validator valid method:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'elementSelector', function(e) {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/prrBQ/1/).